# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException while using RetroFit2 rest client

Tags: retrofit2, put

I need some help with this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Only one HTTP method is allowed Found GET and PUT
```

[image: Interface]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Update]
[image: Image 4]

Comment: I don't know retrofit but I'd guess you have an `@PUT` annotation on the interface definition and an `@GET` on the implementation? Or somewhere else in the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: But please copy and paste code into the question rather than putting it in images, especially multiple images. It's much easier for us to read and understand, and even try ourselves (although you haven't given us quite enough to do that)